# .NET C# WebAPI XmlSerialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am new to C# WebAPIs and I am trying to serialized XML on the return of data from API. Below is a model I have and the XML is not being serialized. The model is being serialized, however only the property names, not the XmlElement attributes on the properties. The JSON serialization works just fine, just not XML.

To return the data in the Controller Action, I am using `Request.CreateResponse<Type>(code, data);`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[XmlType("Chapter")]
public class Chapter
{
    [XmlElement("ChapterNumber"), JsonProperty("ChapterNumber")]
    public Int32 number { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("Verses"), XmlArrayItem("Verse"), JsonProperty("Verses")]
    public List<Verse> verses { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is happening with all models, not just the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to change the formatter**

**Possibility 1: Change input and output formatter**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
}
```

**Posibility 2: Change only outputformatter**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
    });
}
```

**Remark:**

You need package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml, which should be in cluded in Microsof.AspNetCore.All metapackage

Maybe this link will help you for additional questions:
https://andrewlock.net/formatting-response-data-as-xml-or-json-based-on-the-url-in-asp-net-core/